# script.js no funciona con 2 index

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una página web donde agregué un botón para cambiar de idioma. Para ello he creado 2 index (Index.html y IndexES.html) pero dejó de funcionar el archivo main.js

Repositorio en Github del proyecto: https://github.com/RestHouse-20221/RestHouse-LandingPage

[image: 2 indexes]

[image: Ninguna de las funciones del main.js funciona]

Comment: Quizá en el indexES.hrml no incluyes el script.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Si los incluyo en ambos :(

Comment: Podrías poner el código como texto, [formateado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) por favor? Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880

Comment: @DanteS. Claro! Este es el repositorio de github https://github.com/RestHouse-20221/RestHouse-LandingPage

Comment: Las preguntas deben ser autocontenidas para que el tiempo no borre los enlaces externos y éstas pierdan todo el sentido. Léete [ask] y [example] para aprender a realizar buenas preguntas y como poner un buen ejemplo en la misma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se solucionó eliminando esta línea de código que estaba fallando
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias a todos

Comment: Hola, tu respuesta está mal elaborada. Por favor, edita tu respuesta eliminado la imagen y cargando el codigo que has utilizado.